# Polymode: customise buffer names

Tags: polymode

Polymode creates a distinct buffer for each mode involved.
Some use really inconvenient names, where the mode part of the name is easily longer than the actual document name itself, e.g. `foo.Rmd[poly-head-tail]`.

Is it possible, if not eliminate the `[]` part of the buffer name, at least customise it.